# Two different applications with one sqlite

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have two different applications in android and I want to connect them with one sqlite database. 
Is it possible?
How can I do that?

Comment: Instead of data/data folder create your database at root of your sd card or phone memory. That way I think both apps would be able to access it

Answer (score 1):

You can share data! for security if you want to share between just your app, you should sign with same keys.

Secondly, you need to use [Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) to share data. [Some tutorial about Content Provider on CodePath](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Creating-Content-Providers)